# When a list is not a list

Tags: list-manipulation, localization

When I provide a list of local variables to Module, it complains that it is not a list:

v = {x, y};
Module[v, x = 2]

... Module: Local variable specification v is not a List.

So my question is how do I achieve the above (with list v specified outside of Module) without error?

Comment: I guess, you should correct the syntax inside `Module`

Comment: `Evaluate` is useful for constructions like this. Something like `Module[Evaluate[v], x=2]`.

Comment: Thank you! Evaluate[v] solves my problem.

Comment: Try this: `v = {x, y}; Module[{v}, x = 2]`.  This is due to the intrinsic pattern of arguments to `Module`.

Comment: If you evaluate `Attributes[Module]` you will see that `Module` has the attribute `HoldAll`. This is why `Evaluate` is needed.

Answer (score 2):

`Module[{x},expr]` specifies that occurrences of the symbols x in expr should be treated as local.

When you forget to put `x in {}`, you will get this

```
In[1]:= Module[x, y]

During evaluation of In[1]:= Module::lvlist: Local variable specification x is not a List.

Out[1]= Module[x, y]
```

The correct way is:

```
In[2]:= Module[{x}, y]

Out[2]= y
```